# How to put keyboard input values into an array using a loop?

Tags: java

Here I was trying to get two keyboard inputs from the user into a single array index position.

```
 /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package tour;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import tour.City;

    /**
     *
     * @author dp
     */
    public class Tour {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here

            City[] city = new City[9];

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            for(int i=0;i<city.length;i++)
            {
                int no = in.nextInt();
                String name = in.nextLine();

                city[i]= new City(no,name);
            }
        }

    }
```

When I run this code it'll give me the following exception.[image]

I'm very new to java and don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `12` and `NY` are on different lines, when you do

```
String name = in.nextLine();
```

the `String` that you get back is empty. This is because the `Scanner`'s "reading point" is positioned after `12`, but before the end-of-line marker that follows it.

You can fix this by adding another `nextLine`, and dropping its result:

```
in.nextLine(); // Skip to end-of-line after the number
String name = in.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `nextInt()` and `nextLine()` methods to read user inputs, these methods read the `next` available token, so this is how the existing code is working:

- It reads a number using `nextInt()` and assigns it to `no`
- User then hits `return` and control reads an empty line (as next line is empty) and assigns it to `name`
- `City` object gets created with `12` as `no` and `<empty_string>` as `name`. For loop starts it's second execution.
- By this time, user has typed `NY` and hits return
- As it expects the token to be an int (by calling `nextInt()`), it fails and throws an Exception.

If you want the control to read the two inputs separately (and wait until user hits return), use:

```
int no = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
String name = in.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

just need to read the int to the last of line

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package tour;

import java.util.Scanner;
import tour.City;

/**
 *
 * @author dp
 */
public class Tour {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        City[] city = new City[9];

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i=0;i<city.length;i++)
        {
            int no = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();//read to the end of line 
            String name = in.nextLine();

            city[i]= new City(no,name);
        }
    }

}
```